# accessing values of param array

Tags: perl

Not sure how to word my question but I am trying to create an array or photo captions that is being posted to my script.

```
 my $q = CGI->new();
 my $name = $q->param('name');
 my @photoCaptions = $q->param('photos[]');
```

if I dump $q here is the part of where photos is

```
'photos[][caption]' => [ 'cap1', 'cap2', 'cap3', 'cap4', 'cap5' ]
```

but when I dump @photoCaptions, I get nothing.. why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: The name of the parameter is `photos[][caption]` but you use `photos[]` in your call to `param()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your key is `'photos[][caption]'`.

So you will have to call `my @photoCaptions = $q->param('photos[][caption]');`

Comment: I seem to be lost in my own insanity because I thought I tried that and it didnt change anything. But sure enough I try it now and it works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Oh I know but there is a 10 min window where you cant accept answers.